# grab values from checkboxes in contact form and $_POST email

Tags: php, html, forms, post

My question is: I am trying to grab values from checkboxes and send them in an email message. Right now all I am getting is the word None. Tried many different answers given on stackoverflow but none work so far.

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_Email       = "myemail@test.test"; //Replace with recipient email address
    $subject        = 'Poruka'; //Subject line for emails


    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        //exit script outputting json data
        $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'type'=>'error', 
            'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
        ));

        die($output);
    } 
    $user_Docs  = 'None';
if(isset($_POST['dokument']) && is_array($_POST['dokument']) && count($_POST['dokument']) > 0){ 
    $user_Docs = implode('|', $_POST['dokument']);
}

    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    //if(!isset($_POST["name"]) || !isset($_POST["email"]) || !isset($_POST["telefon"]) || !isset($_POST["objekt"]))
    //{
        //$output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Input fields are empty!'));
        //die($output);
    //}

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Phone       = filter_var($_POST["telefon"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Obj     = filter_var($_POST["obj"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Kva  = filter_var($_POST["kva"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Izg    = filter_var($_POST["god_izg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Ces      = filter_var($_POST["kat_ces"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Opc     = filter_var($_POST["kat_opc"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Nam       = filter_var($_POST["nam"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Nap       = filter_var($_POST["nap"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);



    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<4) // If length is less than 4 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!is_numeric($user_Phone)) //check entered data is numbers
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Only numbers allowed in phone field'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($user_Obj)<3) //check emtpy message
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short obj! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!is_numeric($user_Kva)<0) //check emtpy message
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short kva! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!is_numeric($user_Izg)<0) //check emtpy message
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short izg! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($user_Ces)<0) //check emtpy message
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short ces! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($user_Opc)<0) //check emtpy message
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short opc! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($user_Nam)<0) //check emtpy message
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short nam! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }
    /* if(strlen($user_Nap)<0) //check emtpy message
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short nap! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    } */

    // Construct email body
    $body_message = 'Od: ' . $user_Name . "\r\n";
    $body_message .= 'E-mail: ' . $user_Email . "\r\n";
    $body_message .= 'Telefon: ' . $user_Phone . "\r\n";
    $body_message .= 'Nov: ' . $user_Ob  . "\r\n";
    $body_message .= 'Kva: ' . $user_Kva . "\r\n";
    $body_message .= 'God: ' . $user_Izg . "\r\n";
    $body_message .= 'Kat. čes: ' . $user_Ces  . "\r\n";
    $body_message .= 'Kat. opć: ' . $user_Opc  . "\r\n";
    $body_message .= 'Nam: ' . $user_Nam  . "\r\n";
    $body_message .= 'Nap: ' . $user_Nap  . "\r\n"; 
    $body_message .= 'Dodatno: ' . $user_Docs . "\r\n";

    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $body_message .'  -'.$user_Name, $headers);

    if(!$sentMail)
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_Name .' Thank you for your email'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

HTML checkbox inputs contain brackets as noted to use by many users on stackoverflow

```
<label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="Tlocrt objekta" name="dokument[]" > Tlocrt objekta </input>
    </label>
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Građevinska dozvola" name="dokument[]" > Građevinska dozvola </input>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Glavni projekt" name="dokument[]" > Glavni projekt </input>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Izvedbeni projekt" name="dokument[]" > Izvedbeni projekt </input>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Elaborat legalizacije" name="dokument[]" > Elaborat legalizacije </input>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Elaborat etažiranja" name="dokument[]" > Elaborat etažiranja </input>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Projekt preuređenja" name="dokument[]" > Projekt preuređenja </input>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Završno izvješće nadzornog inženjera" name="dokument[]" > Završno izvješće nadzornog inženjera </input>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit_btn").click(function() { 
        //get input field values
        var user_Name       = $('input[name=name]').val();
        var user_Email      = $('input[name=email]').val();
        var user_Phone      = $('input[name=telefon]').val();
        var user_Objekt      = $('input[name=objekt]').val();
        var user_Kvadratura      = $('input[name=kvadratura]').val();
        var user_Izgradnja      = $('input[name=god_izgradnje]').val();
        var user_Cestica      = $('input[name=kat_cestica]').val();
        var user_Opcina      = $('input[name=kat_opcina]').val();
        var user_Namjena      = $('input[name=namjena]').val();
        var user_Napomena    = $('textarea[name=napomena]').val();
        var user_Docs       =    $("input:checkbox[name=dokument]:checked");

        //simple validation at client's end
        //we simply change border color to red if empty field using .css()
        var proceed = true;
        if(user_Name==""){
            $('input[name=name]').css('border-color','red');
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(user_Email==""){
            $('input[name=email]').css('border-color','red');
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(user_Phone=="") {    
            $('input[name=telefon]').css('border-color','red');
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(user_Objekt=="") {    
            $('input[name=objekt]').css('border-color','red');
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(user_Kvadratura=="") {    
            $('input[name=kvadratura]').css('border-color','red');
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(user_Izgradnja=="") {    
            $('input[name=god_izgradnje]').css('border-color','red');
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(user_Cestica=="") {    
            $('input[name=kat_cestica]').css('border-color','red');
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(user_Opcina=="") {    
            $('input[name=kat_opcina]').css('border-color','red');
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(user_Namjena=="") {    
            $('input[name=namjena]').css('border-color','red');
            proceed = false;
        }
        /* if(user_Napomena=="") {    
            $('texarea[name=napomena]').css('border-color','red');
            proceed = false;
        } */

        //everything looks good! proceed...
        if(proceed) 
        {
            //data to be sent to server
            post_data = {'name':user_Name, 'email':user_Email, 'telefon':user_Phone, 'objekt':user_Objekt, 'kvadratura':user_Kvadratura, 'god_izgradnje':user_Izgradnja, 'kat_cestica':user_Cestica, 'kat_opcina':user_Opcina, 'namjena':user_Namjena, 'napomena':user_Napomena};

            //Ajax post data to server
            $.post('contact_me.php', post_data, function(response){  

                //load json data from server and output message     
                if(response.type == 'error')
                {
                    output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
                }else{
                    output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';

                    //reset values in all input fields
                    $('#contact_form input').val(''); 
                    $('#contact_form textarea').val(''); 
                }

                $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
            }, 'json');

        }
    });

    //reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
    $("#contact_form input, #contact_form textarea").keyup(function() { 
        $("#contact_form input, #contact_form textarea").css('border-color',''); 
        $("#result").slideUp();
    });

});
</script>
```

what i need in the end is to get an email which contains values from checkboxes. Not getting them so far. Everything else in form works. Thank for all replys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to serialize() your form data insted of concating it in this way.

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

So your post_data should look like this:

```
post_data = $('form#yourForm').serialize();
```

Comment: dont know what you mean by var_dump your $_POST. Maybe I should have notted that I was a beginner.

Comment: I dont have a form  i have a <fieldset id="contact_form">

Comment: In PHP put var_dump($_POST) to see what variables were posted. Just put it after <?php

Comment: According to standards fieldset should be a part of form. So you should just put your fieldset inside form.

Comment: definitelly not ready to use serialize couse i dont know what to do next after serialize. right now i am very confused couse i thought it was an error in passing values and now i need to change part of code i know little about. Very gratefull to you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Though you create the variable, you don't seem to send `user_Docs` in your javascript:

```
        //data to be sent to server
        post_data = {
            'name':user_Name,   
            'email':user_Email,   
            'telefon':user_Phone, 
            'objekt':user_Objekt, 
            'kvadratura':user_Kvadratura, 
            'god_izgradnje':user_Izgradnja, 
            'kat_cestica':user_Cestica, 
            'kat_opcina':user_Opcina, 
            'namjena':user_Namjena, 
            'napomena':user_Napomena
        };
        // where is user_Docs??
```

As indicated by the other answer, you should try using JQuery `serialize` with the form content. Drop your own json code, and use instead:

```
    post_data = $('form #form_id').serialize();
```

Then, in your PHP script, you should get everything in the `$_REQUEST` array with the names used in the form.

Comment: When you say this I start thinking about this part of the code `var user_Docs   =  $("input:checkbox[name=dokument]:checked");` and this `post_data = {'name':user_Name, 'email':user_Email, 'telefon':user_Phone, 'objekt':user_Objekt, 'kvadratura':user_Kvadratura, 'god_izgradnje':user_Izgradnja, 'kat_cestica':user_Cestica, 'kat_opcina':user_Opcina, 'namjena':user_Namjena, 'napomena':user_Napomena};`

Comment: When you say this I start thinking about this part of the code `var user_Docs   =  $("input:checkbox[name=dokument]:checked");`                                          I am not even sure I am geting an array in $user_Docs for me to send anywhere

Answer (score 0):

the answer was serializing [link]http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ 
which means replacing this part of code 
`//data to be sent to server
            post_data = {'name':user_Name, 'email':user_Email, 'telefon':user_Phone, 'objekt':user_Objekt, 'kvadratura':user_Kvadratura, 'god_izgradnje':user_Izgradnja, 'kat_cestica':user_Cestica, 'kat_opcina':user_Opcina, 'namjena':user_Namjena, 'napomena':user_Napomena, 'dokument[]':user_Docs};`

with this one 
 `post_data = $('form#yourForm').serialize();` 
well not exactly as is. I changed the ID and put my own Form ID, actualy Fieldset ID